# onMessageRecieved never fired Firebase notifications

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

my on MessageRecieved method never gets fired in my Android app although the service is running and the manifest seems to be fine. We are sending messages through the firebase console and nothing ever seems to happen. Also the onToken refresh method is only ever called once and that is when you first install the application. After that, it is never called. I have tested the app in the foreground and background and still the onMessageRecieve method is not called.

Here is my manifest

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.example.beatrice.mylocalbartender">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            tools:node="replace"
            tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">

            <!-- meta data to connect ot the facebook api -->

            <service
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"
                android:name=".messaging.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </service>

            <service
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"
                android:name=".messaging.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_
    EVENT"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </service>


            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@drawable/bt_ic_android_pay" />
            <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
                 notification message.  for more. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
                android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />


            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled" android:value="true"/>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />




            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

            <activity android:name=".messaging.MainActivity"></activity>
            <activity android:name=".activity.GmailSignInActivity">

            </activity>

            <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>

            <!-- activity for brain tree, please do not touch -->
            <activity
                android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                    <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <!-- This activity will be removed in the future -->

            <activity
                android:name=".activity.FacebookLogInActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_facebook_log_in"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            </activity>


            <!-- to launch facebook activity - please do not touch -->

            <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />

            <activity enter code hereandroid:name="com.braintreepayments.api.dropin.DropInActivity"></activity>
            <activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.dropin.AddCardActivity"></activity>



        </application>

    </manifest>
```

As you can see the services are enabled and exported. 
 Here are the services

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    private static final String FRIENDLY_ENGAGE_TOPIC = "friendly_engage";

    /**
     * The Application's current Instance ID token is no longer valid
     * and thus a new one must be requested.
     */

    public MyFirebaseInstanceIdService(){
        super();
        Log.d("startedServiceNoLie","hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
    }


    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // If you need to handle the generation of a token, initially or
        // after a refresh this is where you should do that.
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        Log.d(TAG, "FCM Token: " + token);
    }
}
```

And this is the FirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFMService";

    public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
        super();
        Log.d("startedMessageRecieved","messagingService");

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // Handle data payload of FCM messages.
        Log.d("messageRecieved", "FCM Message Id: " + remoteMessage.getMessageId());
        Log.d("messageRecieved", "FCM Notification Message: " +
                remoteMessage.getNotification());
        Log.d("messageRecieved", "FCM Data Message: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }
}
```

And this is the activity from where is both services are being called from

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button launch_msg_app;
   // private static DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.deletethislayout);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyFirebaseInstanceIdService.class);

        Log.d("tokenNotRefresh",FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
        startService(intent);


        startService(new Intent(this, MyFirebaseMessagingService.class));

        //startService(new Intent(this, DeleteService.class));
    }
```

Here is my project . gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my app .gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.beatrice.mylocalbartender"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'

        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'

        // Google
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'

        // Firebase
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:10.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0'

        // Payments
        compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
        compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.+'
        compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:10.2.0'
        compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'

    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is driving us crazy and I do not know why it does not receive a message. Again we are sending messages from the firebase notification console. We have a sent a message to the whole application and it still does nothing. Please help us. Thank you so much.

Comment: did you have the `google_service.json` in your project?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have no idea why it does not work. I am running firebase messaging 10.0.0. Would this make a difference. In the docs they use 10.2.0?

Comment: I updated everything to 10.2.0 and still nothing. I have sent messages while the app is in the foreground and while the app is in the background and nothing.

Comment: Resolved why updating did not work. In the manifest I had "tools:node="replace"" and that was the reason that it was not changing my dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove Firebase.initializeApp(this) from onCreate
. It's unneeded and may be the issue

Comment: Funny enough, I have never had to do this with Firebase, but when I run the activity. Firebase throws me this exception and tells me to put it in otherwise the application crashes. I'll see if I can remove it

Comment: When I remove it I cannot get the FirebaseInstance and therefore cannot get the token. Firebase throws me this error and crashes the app.         java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.beatrice.mylocalbartender. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

Comment: I've never used this call for my apps. Anyway you may find in firebase docs that this call is recommended to be from Application level rather from Activity. I may suppose that, being called in your way, this may reinit your app and dismiss your previous token. It's just suggestion

Comment: I have updated all grade dependencies for firebase to 10.2.0 and I get this error every time I try and get the token

Comment: I never used to use the call either, I never had to. But recently I have just been getting this error and to get around it I had to initialise the application

Comment: I recommend to use snippets from the firebase docs. I had issues that looked fine but was different from their recommendations and led me to strange issues. Just try to follow each step from the Cloud messaging part for Android.

Comment: And one more thing, don't mix versions for firebase libs. I see in your config 10.0.0 and 10.2.0 - use the same for all

Comment: Thanks, I amended that and made sure all of them are 10.2.0. Still for some reasone the app has to be initialised

Comment: This is the reason why it was not working. I started a new firebase project and kept the dependencies at 10.2.0 and notifs do work. However, although I updated this project to 10.2.0 I cannot get rid of Firebase.InitialiseApp(context) and it is still forcing me to do that. Still, at least I know why it was not working in my project. Thank you, again

Answer (score 1):

As I can't comment yet:

I'm not pretty sure what "android-enabled" and "android-exported" tags mean and do in your service declaration in the manifest. Anyway it works for me even without these tags.

My MessagingService looks a little bit different:

The constructor is empty (not even calling super(...)).
 But I call

```
super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
```

in my onMessageReceived method.

Try to add it to your onMessageReceived method :)

Edit:
I use only 2 Permissions which are required to override the "do not disturb"-mode and to start a service when the device boot was completed.

My manifest looks like this (just FCM part):

```
<application>
<service android:name=".MyAppFirebaseService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name=".MyApp_FirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

My service looks like this:

```
public class MyAppFirebaseService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public MyAppFirebaseService() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // ...
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        String title = "Title";
        String message = "Message";


        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        }
        //My method to display (create) the notification
        //Basically contains a notification(compat)builder
        displayNotifcation(title, message);

    }
}
```

Too see how the notification builder works just read this documentation:
[Android Developer Notification.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html)

Comment: I tried that and still nothing. It doesn't even work when I run it on the emulator. Is there some sort of permission I am missing?

Comment: I added what you have and unfortunately, it still does not work. Another weird issue is that I can only send a message to a token once from the firebase console. Even if the token does not refresh it still fails when I send a message to the same token again. When I send a message to the token initially, the firebase console does say it was 'completed' but I obviously see nothing on my Android application

Comment: Thanks for all your help! That was not the issue but I appreciate your help so much. Thanks

Comment: No problem. So the only problems were the dependencies?

Comment: Yes, but when I change the dependencies to 10.2.0 it still does not work. It still requires that I use FirebaseApp.initialise(context) in order for me to start using firebase. But on other projects that I have with 10.2.0 it works fine. I cannot get his project working even if I update the dependancies .

Answer (score 0):

When sending a message you have to use some named channel, and your app should be subscribed on this channel using subscribeOnTopic("tome_topic").

In example, for channel "news", you will send messages to "/topics/news" channel, and your app have to be subscribed on this channel in order to receive messages:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeOnTopic("news");
```

Just add this into your onTokenRefresh() callback or call where you want.

If you don't want to receive messages from "news" channel, use
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("news");

Note, that when sending from your app server, you should use "/topics/news" for channel name, but in your app you use only "news".

And regarding to only one call of onTokenRefresh() - its ok that it isn't called each restart of app. The firebase client library stores token between restarts and does refresh only when it's needed.

Comment: I am trying to send messages to a single user. Not those subscribed to a topic. The problem is when I send messages directly to that token, the firebase console gives me an unregistered token error. I do not understand why I get this error as the token has not been refreshed so how can it be unregistered

Comment: The token, as far as I understand, is generated by the firebase cloud. So I may suppose that you probably used configuration file json from another firebase app, or your token is absent. You can check your token presence any time by FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken().

Comment: This is the way I am getting the token because the onTokenRefresh rarely ever fires. Once I get this token I then go to the firebase notifications console. Enter the token and send a message.When I use the token for the first time the console says it 'completed' sending the message. However, nothing happens on the Android application. Even if the token does not refresh and I send the message again to the same token, Firebase throws me an 'unregistered token' error.  I also tried sending a message to the entire application through 'user segment' but nothing.

Comment: And the configuration file is correct. The Google services JSON file is the correct one and is pointing to the correct project.

Answer (score 0):

Remove tools:node="replace" from your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

```
I struggled with same issue 5days, code everything fine but firebase registrationnid not generating Notifications iam not receiving from firbase console, Finally i got solution

   <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            tools:node="replace"
            tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">

Everything happend because of this Line inside Application tag      tools:node="replace"
Please remove this line it will work Perfectly sorry for my english.
```